# How do the units of my dependent variable change if I normalize the independent variables before regressing?

Tags: regression, multiple-regression

If I normalize X the units of y change, so how do I interpret the output?

Answer (score 1):

The units of $Y$ would not change if you standardize $X$. However, your interpretation of the coefficients would change. With standardized data, a slope coefficient refers to the effect of a 1-standard-deviation move in that $X$ variable.